# What is more efficient: $self->method or $_[0]->method?

Tags: performance, perl, self

A Perl method usually begins with `my $self = shift;` and subsequently uses `$self` to refer to the object of which it is a method.

```
sub foo {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->method;
  ...
  return $self->{_foo}
}
```

Another way of doing this is to use `$_[0]` directly instead of copying `$_[0]` to  `$self`:

```
sub foo {
  $_[0]->method;
  ...
  return $_[0]->{_foo}
}
```

Now, what is more efficient (faster):

1. to allocate memory to a new variable `$self`, fetch the first item of list `@_`, and copy this value to that variable every single time a method is invoked;
2. to fetch the first item of an array every time `$_[0]` is used?

Comment: You're gaining nothing with `$_[0]->method` in terms of speed (similar to single vs. double quotes "optimization"), only losing source readability.

Comment: This kind of micro-optimization is like changing the paint on your car to make it go faster. Unless you're a Formula One driver, the difference will be negligible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, if you have sufficiently-high-resolution benchmarking tools, using `$_[0]` should be marginally faster, at least in cases where you only use it once or twice in a `sub`.  If you reference the object several times in the same method, `$self` may instead win out due to the larger number of array operations being avoided.

And all of that is **absolutely, utterly meaningless.**

I've been working with Perl as my primary language for the last 15 years.  I currently work as one of three maintainers for a Perl web service which handles a few million requests per day.  If you added up the difference in processing time between using `$_[0]` or `$self` in every method call in every invocation of every Perl program I've ever touched, it would *still* add up to less time than you spent asking the question or I spent answering it.  Probably even less time than it's taking me to write this sentence.  The difference really is that tiny.

So optimize for readability instead of trying to micro-optimize performance.  Your maintenance programmers (including future-you in six months) will thank you for it.

Answer (score 5):

Pure performance wise, `$_[0]` is faster.

- It avoids creation of a new variable
- It avoids shifting the array `@_`
- The only cost is accessing by index.

However this difference is really minimal in computing nowadays. The first one is generally recommended for clarity.